# Boosting an Elasticsearch result by 'age' if applicable

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search multiple indices in Elasticsearch (news items in search_news and documents in search_documents) and whenever an index has a publicationDate field (news items only), I want to 'sort' this, so I boost newer news items. I am using Elasticsearch 6.8.

I found the script_scoring example in https://dzone.com/articles/23-useful-elasticsearch-example-queries (last one). But this throws errors and based on the documentation I came up to

```
GET /search_*/_search
{
    "query": {
      "function_score": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "Lorem Ipsum"
              }
            },
            "must_not": {
                  "exists": {
                      "field": "some_exlusion_field"
                  }
              }
          }
        },
        "script_score": {
          "script": {
              "params" : {
                  "threshold": "2019-04-04"
              },
              "source": "publishDate = doc['publishDate'].value;  if (publishDate > Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', threshold).getTime()) { return log(2.5) } return log(1);"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This  results in the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "compile error",
        "script_stack": [
          "publishDate = doc['publis ...",
          "^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "publishDate = doc['publishDate'].value;  if (publishDate > Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', threshold).getTime()) { return log(2.5) } return log(1);",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
}
```

I managed to minify the source to:
`"source": "if (doc['publishDate'] > '2019-04-04') { return 5 } return 1;"`
But no success:

```
"failures" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "search_document_page",
        "node" : "c0iLpxiJRqmgwS0KY8OybA",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "runtime error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:81)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:39)",
            "if (doc['publishDate'] > '2019-04-04') { ",
            "        ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script" : "if (doc['publishDate'] > '2019-04-04') { return 5 } return 1;",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "No field found for [publishDate] in mapping with types []"
          }
        }
      },
     {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "search_news",
        "node" : "c0iLpxiJRqmgwS0KY8OybA",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "runtime error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "if (doc['publishDate'] > '2019-04-04') { ",
            "       ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script" : "if (doc['publishDate'] > '2019-04-04') { return 5 } return 1;",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "class_cast_exception",
            "reason" : "Cannot apply [>] operation to types [org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Dates] and [java.lang.String]."
          }
        }
      }
    ] 
  }
}
```

Any suggestion for checking the existence of the field in doc and how to check the date properly?

Answer (score 0):

For the existence check ( [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals) ) :

```
if (!doc.containsKey('publishDate')) {
    return 1;
}
```

And for the date comparison, you can try [this way](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/comparison-not-supported-on-datetime-fields-anymore-since-upgrade-to-6-1/118008)

```
if (Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', params.threshold).getMillis() > doc['publishDate'].getMillis()) {
    return 5;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The Date.parse gives me an compile error. Also the .getMillis on the doc['publishDate'] didn't work. So I changed the use to:
`def sf = new SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd\");
if (doc['publishDate'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli() > sf.parse('2019-04-04').getTime()) {    
    return 5; 
}    
return 1;
`

Comment: I'm glad that you found a way!